# sql connect different rows

Tags: sql, oracle, compare, rows

Recently I met a question in oracle sql. Took many times trying to figure it out, but it seems very hard to achieve. So if anyone can help, that would be great!

The problem is straightforward that I want to connect duplicates in different rows, in order to find the "real start" and "real end" for example,

```
ID  Start date  End date    Line
1   8/25/2013   8/27/2013   1
1   8/27/2013   8/30/2013   2
2   8/20/2013   8/27/2013   1
2   9/1/2013    9/4/2013    2
2   9/4/2013    9/5/2013    3
2   9/5/2013    9/7/2013    4
```

So as you can see, for the same ID, it has multiple "start" and "end", but some of them are consistent (the end date is the same as its following start date). what I want to do is to sort the data and get rid off some duplicates. For examples, the results should be,

```
ID  Start date  End date
1   8/25/2013   8/30/2013
2   8/20/2013   8/27/2013
2   9/1/2013    9/7/2013
```

Really appreciate if someone can offer some hint. I tried "lead" function, but it seems it needs more than that to solve this problem. Also, I try to copy this query to Access, which you know don't have too much fancy functions, so second question becomes whether this even can be achieved in Access. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem. May I ask where did you find it? Below is my proposal. I haven't tested it thoroughly yet, but I will, for I am also interested in finding a proper solution to this problem. The hard part is to find all the records for the `START WITH` clause, but for the data I have used for tests it returned correct result set. I hope somebody will post an easier solution, perhaps using analytic functions (didn't succeed in that attempt myself).

Ok, here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (
  id NUMBER,
  start_date DATE,
  end_date DATE,
  line NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO my_data VALUES (1, DATE '2013-08-25', DATE '2013-08-27', 1);
INSERT INTO my_data VALUES (1, DATE '2013-08-27', DATE '2013-08-30', 2);
INSERT INTO my_data VALUES (2, DATE '2013-08-20', DATE '2013-08-27', 1);
INSERT INTO my_data VALUES (2, DATE '2013-09-01', DATE '2013-09-04', 2);
INSERT INTO my_data VALUES (2, DATE '2013-09-04', DATE '2013-09-05', 3);
INSERT INTO my_data VALUES (2, DATE '2013-09-05', DATE '2013-09-07', 4);

COMMIT;

SELECT
    id,
    root_start_date AS start_date,
    MAX(end_date) AS end_date
  FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT start_date AS root_start_date
      FROM my_data
    START WITH (id, start_date) IN (
                            SELECT id, start_date
                              FROM my_data md
                            WHERE
                              NOT EXISTS (
                                SELECT 1
                                  FROM my_data
                                WHERE id = md.id
                                  AND md.start_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
                                  AND end_date < md.end_date
                                )
    )
    CONNECT BY start_date >= PRIOR start_date
            AND start_date <= PRIOR end_date
            AND end_date > PRIOR end_date
            AND id = PRIOR id
  )
GROUP BY id, root_start_date
ORDER BY id, start_date
;
```

Result:

```
        ID START_DATE END_DATE
---------- ---------- --------
         1 13/08/25   13/08/30 
         2 13/08/20   13/08/27 
         2 13/09/01   13/09/07
```

Comment: thank you so much @PrzemyslawK ! it does help and works on my Oracle toad. It's a case from my work. When I deal with the data, I always try to sort them and make it easier to work with. It's really helpful to know the functions of "start with" and "connect". Really appreciate your help!

Comment: by the way, @PrzemyslawK, what kind of analytic functions you are using, can you explain a little bit more... thanks for sharing!

Comment: @user2679074 No problem, I'm glad I could help and that I have found solution because I have faced similar problem a while ago and didn't find a solution back then. Do you mean by your latter comment that you'd like me to explain what's going on in the query I proposed?

Comment: thanks, I got the meaning of your query. What I trying to say was that since you talked about maybe other analytic functions can provide a easier solution, I wonder what they could be, so I can have a try as well.

Comment: @user2679074 Unfortunately I don't know how to use analytic functions to solve this problem, or if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, I'd be tempted to try it out with more data, but in essence, all I did was to ensure that the combination of (id, start_date) doesn't exist as (id, end_date).

I suppose the fallacy could come when a particular id has the same start and end date--you should test it out.

Hopefully this gets you 80% there (however, it works and returns your desired output):

```
SELECT id, start_date
  FROM table1 mst
 WHERE (id, start_date) NOT IN (SELECT id, end_date FROM table1)
```

Validation (sqlfidddle): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6116f/20/0

Comment: thanks for help @RobertoN, I think it's the right logic to start with.

Comment: Feel free to accept my solution if it's going to work for you :)